# Creating simple chat using telegram bot api

Tags: android, chat, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to make simple chat (I mean user-user architecture) in my android app without own server. Can I do this using telegram bot api only?

If not, is there any free chat services for making simple chats in android app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Applozic](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK) open source Chat and Messaging SDK that lets you add real time messaging in your mobile (android, iOS) applications and website. It is and very easy to integrate. It will just take you hardly 10-15 minutes to integrate to your app. Using it since 6 months. Didn't faced any issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

MirrorFly's [FREE chat API](https://www.mirrorfly.com/chat-api-solution.php) is one of the options you can use to build an user-user architecture without your own server. Telegram Bot is a good option but the APIs are subject to [request and rate limits](https://rapidapi.com/m0s4ik/api/telegram7/pricing).